# CoreUI: Try to npm install the downloaded free version of CoreUI to try the dashboard

Tags: reactjs, npm, dashboard, core-ui

I receiving the error below after download the free CoreUI for react and call npm install. My impression was the come incorrect dependency was the issue but I am not quite understand what it was talking about from the error.

```
>  Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react@"0.13.x || 0.14.x || ^15.0.0-0 || ^16.0.0-0" from enzyme-adapter-utils@1.14.0
npm WARN node_modules/enzyme-adapter-utils
npm WARN   enzyme-adapter-utils@"^1.13.1" from @wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17@0.3.2
npm WARN   node_modules/@wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^17.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@"^17.0.1" from @coreui/icons-react@1.1.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@coreui/icons-react
npm ERR!     @coreui/icons-react@"^1.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!     @coreui/icons-react@"^1.1.0" from @coreui/react@3.4.6
npm ERR!     node_modules/@coreui/react
npm ERR!       @coreui/react@"^3.4.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   8 more (@coreui/react, react-dom, react-router-dom, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^0.14 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0-alpha" from airbnb-prop-types@2.16.0
npm ERR! node_modules/enzyme-adapter-utils/node_modules/airbnb-prop-types
npm ERR!   airbnb-prop-types@"^2.16.0" from enzyme-adapter-utils@1.14.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/enzyme-adapter-utils
npm ERR!     enzyme-adapter-utils@"^1.13.1" from @wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17@0.3.2
npm ERR!     node_modules/@wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17
npm ERR!       @wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17@"^0.3.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See  AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because @wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17 works with React 17, but uses enzyme-adapter-utils which while also do work with React 17, have no React 17 compatibility declared.

Good news is that @wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17 0.6.0 fixes this issue so you can just install the newest version and the error should disappear.

If you're unable to update the adapter on your own for some reason, you can try and install your project with `--legacy-peer-deps` flag.